# How to Hide Column Group in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to hide a column group in my kendo grid, my column group has five columns under it, i want to hide all the five columns along with column group.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, Please check the url: http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-remove-gridtableview-colgroup-and-thead-from-the-server-side

Comment: Check this too, http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-hide-grouping-column

Comment: I want dynamic show/hide of column, I think this won't work on dynamic case. Only few columns need to get hidden.

Comment: why not just enable the column menu option and then the user is able to decide what columns should be hidden/visible? If you hide all the columns within a column group this will get hidden by the very nature that all columns in that group are hidden. Even with dynamic columns you can still enable them to appear within the column menu. Unless you have a specific scenario that you can expand on or provide a "example" of what should/shouldn't be happening

Comment: on which event you want to show/hide ?

Comment: I want to show/hide on button click.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the columns that are grouped by you should use the event ondatabound of the grid and interact over all grouped columns aka styled with the class .k-group-indicator and hide the column by its data field.

You can take a look at this that can be used as a prof of concept.

http://jsfiddle.net/2gtWv/

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "name"
    }, {
        field: "age"
    }],
    dataSource: ds,
    groupable: true,
    dataBound:function(o){
        var g = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        for(var i=0;i<g.columns.length;i++){
            g.showColumn(i);
        }
        $("div.k-group-indicator").each(function(i,v){
            g.hideColumn($(v).data("field"));
        });
        
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The question is how to hide a group of columns all at once. So for example: "Address" consists of "Street Number", "Street Name", "City", "State", "Zip". How would you hide "Address" and all of it's component columns?